# What is the CHAR2B type?

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, x11

In the [X11 protocol specification](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html), a type called `CHAR2B` is defined, which is just a struct of two bytes: `byte1` and `byte2`. The type is used in only two requests, `QueryTextExtents` and `ImageText16`, both to specify the name of fonts.

My question is this: what is the point of `CHAR2B` and how is it used? The type seems pointless to me because:

- There's a request called `ImageText8` which takes just string of bytes as font name as opposed to string of `CHAR2B` in `ImageText16`.
- Many other requests take common "string of bytes" as input rather than "string of `CHAR2B`", such as `QueryExtension`, `InternAtom`, `OpenFont`, etc.
- `CHAR2B` is only used in 2 requests.

Given that `CHAR2B` is part of the X11 protocol, how does one go about using it? What is the encoding? UTF16? Some other type of two-byte encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is used to specify the text to be displayed, not any font name.
2. It is used in 3 requests (PolyText16). These requests, and their 8-bit counterparts, are the only requests that deal with displaying text.
3. `CHAR2B`s are indices in the font being used to display text. The document you link very clearly states that

> The primary interpretation of large characters in a STRING16 is that they are composed of two bytes used to index a two-dimensional matrix, hence, the use of CHAR2B rather than CARD16. This corresponds to the JIS/ISO method of indexing 2-byte characters. It is expected that most large fonts will be defined with 2-byte matrix indexing. For large fonts constructed with linear indexing, a CHAR2B can be interpreted as a 16-bit number by treating byte1 as the most significant byte. This means that clients should always transmit such 16-bit character values most significant byte first, as the server will never byte-swap CHAR2B quantities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - so it was a misunderstanding on my part. Do you have any resources that I can read for someone who wants to learn more about X11 font?

Comment: Most applications handle fonts client-side these days. My home machine doesn't even have any server side fonts except two mandatory ugly fixed fonts. So, frankly, learning about true X11 fonts is a waste of time (unless you support legacy products).  The library you want to learn is libxft